# UITableView Lags Due a Particular Object

Tags: uitableview, lag, reusability, uiswitch

In the Home Page of my App, I have an `iCarousel` object that scrolls images. Under that there is a `UITableView` - the table view is where the problem is.

Lately I added a `SevenSwitch` object to each `cell` in the table view and since then the scrolling lags a lot! This is the code I added in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
cella.subscribed = [[SevenSwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cella.frame.size.width-60, cella.frame.size.height / 2 - 12, 50, 25)];
cella.subscribed.offImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"off.png"];
cella.subscribed.onImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"on.png"];
cella.subscribed.thumbTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(230/255.0) green:(230/255.0) blue:(230/255.0) alpha:1];
cella.subscribed.activeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(204/255.0) green:(204/255.0) blue:(204/255.0) alpha:1];
cella.subscribed.inactiveColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(204/255.0) green:(204/255.0) blue:(204/255.0) alpha:1];
cella.subscribed.onTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(204/255.0) green:(204/255.0) blue:(204/255.0) alpha:1];
cella.subscribed.isRounded = NO;
cella.subscribed.tag = [[tempCat objectForKey:@"Id"] intValue];

[cella.subscribed addTarget:self action:@selector(changeSingleCategory:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

if ([[tempCat objectForKey:@"Subscribed"] isEqualToString:@"Y"]) {
    cella.subscribed.on = YES;
} else {
    cella.subscribed.on = NO;
}

[cella.contentView addSubview:cella.subscribed];
```

Is there a way to create a custom object without setting it up with all that properties everytime?

Comment: Have you done any profiling to find out what is causing the lag?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the SevenSwitch causes the lag because If I remove it from any cell the lag disappears...

Comment: You need to profile to find out exactly what it is. Are you always recreating the switches? The switch should only be created when the cell is created...

Comment: Yes I always recreate swtiches...

Comment: The first time I scroll down my table view it's done without any lag. The lag starts when I scroll up and down repetely my table view.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of cells in table views is that they are reused. This should not just apply to the cell, but also to the content (subviews).

You must already have a cell subclass so you should put the switch creation and configuration code into that class (and add it as a subview there). Now, each time you create / dequeue a cell you will already have a switch (and hopefully this is reused 99% of the time) and all you need to do is call `cella.subscribed.on = ...` with the appropriate setting.

Answer (score 0):

I have di UITableViewCell.h

```
#import "SevenSwitch.h"

@interface cellaMain : UITableViewCell {

    SevenSwitch *subscribed;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageMain;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *titleMain;
@property (nonatomic,strong) SevenSwitch *subscribed;
```

and added these methods in mi .m file

```
    -(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        subscribed = [[SevenSwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(frame.size.width-60, frame.size.height / 2 - 12, 50, 25)];
        subscribed.offImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"off.png"];
        subscribed.onImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"on.png"];
        subscribed.thumbTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(230/255.0) green:(230/255.0) blue:(230/255.0) alpha:1];
        subscribed.activeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(204/255.0) green:(204/255.0) blue:(204/255.0) alpha:1];
        subscribed.inactiveColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(204/255.0) green:(204/255.0) blue:(204/255.0) alpha:1];
        subscribed.onTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(204/255.0) green:(204/255.0) blue:(204/255.0) alpha:1];
        subscribed.isRounded = NO;
        [self.contentView addSubview:subscribed];

    }

    return self;

}

-(void)layoutSubviews {

    [super layoutSubviews];

}
```

And in the method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I deleted all the previous code and left only this one

```
cella.subscribed.tag = [[tempCat objectForKey:@"Id"] intValue];

[cella.subscribed addTarget:self action:@selector(changeSingleCategory:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

if ([[tempCat objectForKey:@"Subscribed"] isEqualToString:@"Y"]) {
    cella.subscribed.on = YES;
} else {
    cella.subscribed.on = NO;
}
```

Now the problem is that no switch button appears.